# C library fopen fails

Tags: file, url, appstore-sandbox, nsopenpanel, security-scoped-bookmarks

My macOS swift project incorporates a c library. This library has a function, which requires the path for a file as a string, then internally it opens a file at that path and does its stuff.
However it fails to open the file

When the app is run in a sandbox the function successfully opens the fils (e.g. on the root of the container), and everything works fine. As soon as the sandbox is disabled, even if I previously open a OpenPanel instance and grant access to the folder in which the file will be open, the function fails to open the file and "throw" an error.

Which is the proper way to handle this situation? (this app cannot run in a sandbox for other reason, so this is not a valuable option for me)

Comment: Have you tried [turning off sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_app-sandbox?language=objc) in your `.entitlements` file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could it be you mean it the other way round? It only works outside the sandbox? Hope do you create the url and convert it to a string: please show code.

Comment: did you resolve this? running into the same issue but the inverse (sandbox breaks fopen even tho swift can access the file in the app container)

Comment: No, activating the sandbox and  feeding the "/file.name" path to the function opens the file in the root of the container, in which I can do barely everything I want. However disabling it and trying to feed the "~/Desktop/file.name" path breaks open